# ExactTarget API GET /interaction/v1/rest not working/not authorized

Tags: marketing-cloud, rest-api

I can't seem to get the GET /interaction/v1/rest API to function properly.  I receive the following data when I call it:

```
    {'documentation': 'https://code.docs.exacttarget.com/rest/errors/403', 
     'message': 'Not Authorized', 'errorcode': 0
    }
```

I'm using python request and json libaries here is the code snippet:

```
url ="https://www.exacttargetapis.com/interaction/v1/rest"
r = requests.get(url, headers = {"authorization":"bearer " + token});
print (r.json());
```

The token is valid I use it in prior code with other API calls.  I recently as in the past 10 minutes updated the App Center ID with the rights to Read Automation Interactions.  Is that the correct permissions or is something else needed?

Comment: based on the limited info you have provided and {'documentation': 'https://code.docs.exacttarget.com/rest/errors/403', 'message': 'Not Authorized', 'errorcode': 0} have you tried converting your token to a string, this would seem to be causing the error at a first glance

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish with your REST call?

Comment: Getting same error, what was the error?

Comment: In my experience, ExactTarget is case sensitive when you use "Bearer " + ...